# Problem using the Thrift APIs

Tags: cassandra, thrift

I have installed Cassandra on my Ubuntu VM and built the source. I was trying to use the Thrift APIs and it seems like the libthrift-0.5.jar in my bin is not the file that I need in order to interface with the running cassandra instance.

Is there some other way to install the Thrift JARs? I found the

> /cassandra/interface/thrift

folder that has the Thrift source pertaining to the interface with Cassandra. When I tried doing an `ant gen-thrift-java` from the command line, I get a build failed with the following message:

> Execute failed: java.io.IOException:
>   Cannot run program "thrift" (in
>   directory
>   "/home/user/cassandra/interface"):
>   java.io.IOException: error=2, No such
>   file or directory

Can somebody give me some ideas on what do I need to do in order to work with Thrift here?

Thanks

Comment: Anytime somebody is working with raw Thrift, I have to ask the question: why are you not using an already existing high-level client like Hector?

Comment: I am still trying to scale the cassandra learning curve so clients such as 'Hector' is new to me. Some of the cassandra samples out there are working within the context of Thrift/Avro so I was simply trying to replicate their results. The purpose of this is purely educational.

Comment: It also seems like working with raw Thrift is discouraged in the domain. Why is that so?

Comment: Because there are quite a few gotcha's and the same work is inevitably done over and over again with questions to the mailing list, etc.  The learning curve is much better with established client libraries, many of the quirks are already dealt with, and you get nice features like connection pooling, failover, and some amount of cross-version compatibility for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/)

```
$ cd thrift
$ ./bootstrap.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: @Schildmeijer - Thanks. I downloaded Thrift and extracted the files but nowhere do I find the bootstrap.sh file. And the commands make and make install are terminating without doing anything? What else am I missing here?

Comment: bootstrap.sh is only included in source distributions (or maybe just in svn checkouts).  You can skip that step if it's not there.

Comment: @Tyler Hobbs - Thanks. I skipped that step but do I need to specify some targets for "make" and "sudo make install". Both of these commands are failing for me.

Comment: I ran across this link http://blog.ibd.com/scalable-deployment/installing-apache-thrift-on-ubuntu-and-leopard/ . This may be of some help...

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about some of the dependencies.  You can also pass options to configure like '--with-ruby=no' if you don't want ruby libraries.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I was able to build thrift.